# MS Excel Formula Correction

Tags: excel

I am Using below formula to Search some Keywords from Particular Columns. But This one is giving error in Excel may be Excel is limited to 7 Nested IF statements Only.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*SIPC*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*HIU*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*GMC*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*CNS*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*LCSM*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*RoHC*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*GL1*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*GL3*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*GL2*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*URRC*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*UPHY*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*UHAL*",J2,1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("*UMAC*",J2,1)),"","SIPC"),"HIU"),"GMC"),"CNS"),"LCSM"),"RoHC"),"GL1"),"GL3"),"GL2"),"URRC"),"UPHY"),"UHAL")
```

Can anyone Please suggest me any alternatives for this to get more than 10 Nested IF statements.

Thanks in Advance..:)

Comment: The maximum nested IF statement is limited to 7 in Excel. Try VLOOKUP http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: It would be useful to provide some sample data so the use-case is more evident.

Comment: Also, your corrected formula (added the missing end parenthesis) will return `FALSE` if there is `SIPC` somewhere in J2. Not sure if this is intended. Yes, it seems that VLOOKUP and some example would be helpful to devise a better way than nested ifs.

Comment: with VLOOKUP how can I add multiple Key strings to search in Multiple Columns.... Can You Please Suggest.?

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable to use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), [create a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_GettingStartedWithVBAInExcel2010_MacrosAndTheVisualBasicEditor) and define the following function in it:

```vb
public function GetCode(s as string) as string
    GetCode = ""
    codes = split( _
        "SIPC|HIU|GMC|CNS|LCSM|RoHC|GL1|GL3|GL2|URRC|UPHY|UHAL|UMAC", "|")

    for each code in codes
        if InStr(s, code) > 0 then 
            GetCode = code
            exit for
        endif
    next

end function
```

You should then be able to access the function in your formula as follows:

```
= GetCode(J2)
```

Comment: Hi Nirk,

Thanks for Macro code.

But Its acceptable for 1 Columns only. I want to update It to search from Several columns and Getcode in a single column with all the outputs with seperated comma.

Comment: @user2678167 Yes, it's acceptable for 1 column only, because that's what the question is about. The function I posted achieves just that. If you want to aggregate / process the data further / build an ERP system, feel free to post additional questions about that.

Comment: Hi Nirk,

Can you Please tell me that How to combine formula like "=GetCode(J2),Getcode(K2),GetCode(L2)" or "=GetCode(J2:L2)"


I am getting Error with these 2 Formula.